# Название методов

Tags: функции, веб-программирование, javascript

Смотрел яваскрипт одного сайта, он был скомпрессован. Загрузил в бютифулер, начал читать, 90% функций имеют названия a, b, c, d, Z, Q.

Это в целях компрессии или шифровки или это какая-то техника такая, кто-нибудь знает?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно JS код сжимают в целях уменьшения его размера (браузеру все равно, как называются функции и переменные, а вот их длина весит-таки лишние байты). Кроме того, код обфусцируется, маскируя при этом свой внутренний функционал.

Часто в качестве инструмента применяют, например, Uglify, входящий также в комплект Grunt.

Если библиотека Open Source, то, думаю, вы могли заметить, что большинство разработчиков сразу же поставляют функционал для тех, кто не интересуется его исходным кодом в сжатом виде (расширение .min.js), и для тех, кому интересно, что внутри (.js).

Comment: > Uglify, входящий также в комплект Grunt  

?? звучит, как bison, также входящий в комплект make.

Comment: @eicto, казалось, что uglify - инструмент, существовавший и ранее, но затем просто встроенный в grunt. В целом это, конечно же, не так уж и важно, потому как если важна обфускация, можно и любым онлайн обфускатором воспользоваться. Спасибо за комментарий.